# Let $F$ be a probability distribution function. Prove that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x+a)-F(x)\ dx= a\ \forall a\in\Bbb{R}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

A real-valued map $F$ is called a probability distribution if

1. $F$ is monotonically increasing
2. $F$ is right continuous
3. $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} F(x)=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} F(x)=0$

Again I know that for such $F$, there is a probability measure $P$ on borel $\sigma$-field of $\Bbb{R}$. such that $P((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)\ \forall -\infty\le a\le b\le \infty$.

So we have to prove that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}P((x,x+a])\ dx=a$

Here $F$ may not be absolutely continuous, so we cannot work with the probability density function.

I'm not getting any idea how to prove this result. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Not sure how to approx this, but one question. Shouldn't point 3 be $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}F(X)=0$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Corrected

Comment: Although you don't have a probability density function, you do have a probability measure, so you can write $P((x,x+a])=\int_x^{x+a}dP(t)$.

Comment: So by Fubini's theorem $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P((x,x+a])\ dx=\int\limits_{\Bbb{R}}\int\limits_{(x,x+a]}dP(\omega) \ d\lambda(x)=\int\limits_{\omega\in\Bbb{R}}\int\limits_{(\omega-a,\omega]} d\lambda(x)\ dP(\omega)=\int\limits_{\omega\in\Bbb{R}} (\omega-\omega+a)\ dP(\omega)=a$ where $\lambda$ is lebesgue measure . Is it okay?

Comment: @DeltaEpsilon: For clarity, you need to specify the set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ explicitly. You may read my proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu$ be the probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$
induced by $F$ (i.e, $\mu(a,b]=F(b)-F(a))$. Let $m$ be the usual
Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Consider
the product measure space $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),m\times \mu)$.
Fix $a>0$ (the case that $a\leq0$ can be treated similarly). Let
$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid x<y\leq a+x\}$ which is a Borel subset
of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (see remark below). By Fubini-Tonelli Theorem,
$$
\int\left(\int1_{A}(s,t)dm(s)\right)d\mu(t)=\int\left(\int_{A}(s,t)d\mu(t)\right)dm(s).
$$
Observe that for each $s$, $\int1_{A}(s,t)d\mu(t)=\mu\left((s,s+a]\right)=F(s+a)-F(s)$.
Therefore $\int\left(\int_{A}(s,t)d\mu(t)\right)dm(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[F(s+a)-F(s)\right]ds.$
On the other hand, for each $t$, $1_{A}(s,t)=1$ iff $s<t\leq s+a$
iff $s\in[t-a,t)$. Therefore, $\int1_{A}(s,t)dm(s)=m\left([t-a,t)\right)=a$.
It follows that $\int\left(\int1_{A}(s,t)dm(s)\right)d\mu(t)=\int ad\mu(t)=a$.

That is, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[F(s+a)-F(s)\right]ds=a$.

---

Remark: We go to show that $A$ is a Borel set.

Let $A_{1}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid x<y\}$ and $A_{2}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid y>a+x\}$.
Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_{1} & = & \cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\{(x,y)\mid x<r<y\}\\
 & = & \cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\left((-\infty,r)\times\mathbb{R}\right)\cap\left(\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}\times(r,\infty)\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a countable union of measurable rectangles, so it is measurable.
Similarly, $A_{2}$ is measurable. Finally, $A=A_{1}\setminus A_{2}$,
so $A$ is measurable too.

Comment: $A_1$ and $A_2$ are open and hence Borel.

Comment: Who gave me a downvote? That action must be justified (i.e., with reason. For example, gaps in proof), otherwise, I request moderator to take action.

Comment: @ amsmath: Did you downvote my solution? If so, you need to justify your action. I downvoted your solution because you stated that $\int F'(t) dt = 1$, which is wrong. Then, you deleted your post immediately. However, please bear in mind that there is no "true delete" and every actions are recorded. Moderators who have sufficient privilege can find out everything and penalize those who downvote others arbitrarily.